# Can't Retrieve nodeValue from responseXML but can get nodeName?

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

I have a `XMLHttpRequest` for which I receive an XML response.

I am trying to get a specific value from the result using the `responseXML` function and then accessing the node that I want. Below is my code..

```
xmlDoc = request.responseXML;
result = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("result")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
console.log("Result: "+result);
```

Now that outputs `null`. However when I change `nodeValue` for `nodeName` it outputs the name of the node I want. I can see the xml and this is the structure that it receives.

```
<result mime="text/xml">
    <int>1</int>
</result>
```

So to make it clear, when I use `nodeValue` I get null but when I was `nodeName` it outputs `int`.

**My Question**

How do I retrieve the value within the int tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
result = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('int')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. One more question. How do I display the contents of the tag PDOException just as a string? `<PDOException><![CDATA[%00%2A%00message]]><![CDATA[%00Exception%00string]]><![CDATA[%00%2A%00code]]><![CDATA[%00%2A%00file]]><![CDATA[%00%2A%00line]]><![CDATA[%00Exception%00trace]]><![CDATA[%00Exception%00previous]]><property name="errorInfo"><array><item key="0"><str>42S22</str></item><item key="1"><int>1054</int></item><item key="2"><str>Unknown column '3630TYPE' in 'where clause'</str></item></array></property></PDOException> `

Comment: @DiscoS2 pls check this:: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Parsing_and_serializing_XML, it might be of help

Answer (score 0):

> Get the Value of an Element In the DOM, everything is a node. Element nodes do not have a text value.
>
> The text of an element node is stored in a child node. This node is
>   called a text node.
>
> The way to get the text of an element is to get the value of the child
>   node (text node).

[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_get.asp)

The `int` node is an element node. As the article says, the text value you're looking for actually belongs to the child.